# Specifying rootPath for Liquibase via jOOQ generation

Tags: gradle, liquibase, jooq, jooq-codegen

I'm trying to utilize jOOQ's [ability to generate from Liquibase files](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-liquibase/). My file structure is as follows:

```
C
- dev
-- testproject
--- src/main/resources
---- db
----- changelog.xml
```

In order to reference this file from the jOOQ configuration, I have the following in my `build.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
jooq {
    configurations {
        create("main") {
            jooqConfiguration.apply {
                generator.apply {
                    database.apply {
                        name = "org.jooq.meta.extensions.liquibase.LiquibaseDatabase"
                        
                        properties.add(Property().apply {
                            key = "rootPath"
                            value = "C:/dev/testproject/src/main/resources/db/"
                        })

                        properties.add(Property().apply {
                            key = "scripts"
                            value = "changelog.xml"
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using plugin version 7.1.1 and have the following dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("org.liquibase:liquibase-core:4.8.0") // I tried removing this, no change
    jooqGenerator("org.postgresql:postgresql:42.3.2")
    jooqGenerator("org.jooq:jooq-meta-extensions-liquibase:3.17.2")
    jooqGenerator(files("src/main/resources")) // I don't think this is necessary
}
```

When I try to run `jooqGenerate`, the error I get is:

```
Caused by: liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: The file changelog.xml was not found in
Specifying files by absolute path was removed in Liquibase 4.0. Please use a relative path or add '/' to the classpath parameter.
    at liquibase.parser.core.xml.XMLChangeLogSAXParser.parseToNode(XMLChangeLogSAXParser.java:82)
    at liquibase.parser.core.xml.AbstractChangeLogParser.parse(AbstractChangeLogParser.java:15)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.getDatabaseChangeLog(Liquibase.java:369)
```

Notice how it doesn't say which directories it looked in. As far as I can tell, the resource accessor is not receiving the `rootPath` from the configuration. The relevant output from Liquibase is [here](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/d6a9358bbb2eab587989dcb464e4f499ebe39d8c/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/util/FileUtil.java#L76). Again, it should say it looked in the `rootPath`, but it doesn't print anything else, so there must be no directories searched.

Not sure if this is helpful, but the jOOQ configuration file in `build/tmp/generateJooq` definitely has the rootPath:

```xml
                <property>
                    <key>rootPath</key>
                    <value>C:/dev/testproject/src/main/resources/db/</value>
                </property>
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. I've also tried the following values of `scripts` without setting `rootPath` and seen the same behavior:

- `C:/dev/testproject/src/main/resources/db/changelog.xml`
- `src/main/resources/db/changelog.xml`
- `/src/main/resources/db/changelog.xml`
- `classpath:src/main/resources/db/changelog.xml`
- `classpath:/src/main/resources/db/changelog.xml`

Comment: Idk if it makes a difference but, maybe don't include the last slash in `/db/` and/or try testing with a slash in front changelog.xml. The path to the changelog might need to be relative from where your gradle or maven file is located in your project structure

Comment: I've tried every combination of the two and none of them seemed to work. Thanks for the idea though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was causing the problem (or rather, the confusion):

```kotlin
jooqGenerator(files("src/main/resources"))
```

Apparently, this sets the classpath of the `jooqGenerator` task to be `src/main/resources`! So, knowing that, I fixed my configuration to look like this:

```kotlin
                    database.apply {
                        name = "org.jooq.meta.extensions.liquibase.LiquibaseDatabase"
                        
                        properties.add(Property().apply {
                            key = "scripts"
                            value = "classpath:db/changelog.xml"
                        })
                    }
```

Everything is working nicely now.